# Change the mapped index of a list in MongoDB Driver C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization

I have a list of objects that I want to write and access in my MongoDB.
I previously used a `Dictionary<String, MongoPropertyValue>` but the Id doesn't have
to be unique so I would prefer to use a `List<MongoPropertyValue>`. The problem with lists is, that they
appear in MongoDB as follows

[image]

but I need them like in a dictionary

[image]

I assume that I can alter the way how my list is mapped but I am unsure how to accomplish
the mapping.
I concluded that it might work with the help of `IClassMapConvention` but I don't have a clue how to accomplish the mapping.

How can I map a value of an element of my list as the indexer in MongoDB or in other words
how can I Map a `List<T>` like a `Dictionary<K, T>` but without the unique Id?

```
class Propertys : List<MongoPropertyValue>
{
    public Propertys()
    {
        //This Id should be shown as the index
        //just like as it would be in a dictionary
        //MongoPropertyValue.PropertyId
    }

    //methods
}

public class ListLikeDictionaryConvention : IClassMapConvention
{
    public void Apply(BsonClassMap classMap)
    {
        // I guess I can map the PropertyId so that it appears as "index"
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return "ListLikeDictionary"; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use Dictionary<String, List<MongoPropertyValue>>?

Comment: @jdweng I want to reproduce the same structure as before but without the dictionary. Using a dictionary with a list in it would result in a different structure I guess.

Comment: The dictionary won;t change the structure of the classes.  The dictionary is just a link to the original classes that makes it easier to lookup the data.

Comment: @jdweng I tried it, but it isn't what I am looking for. Underneath the Key (that I want) I have now a list of elements which means I don't have access to the object but rather access to the array/list and within it the object.

Comment: What is the difference?  To find an id both ways you end up with a list of objects with the same id.  Using a dictionary you get the list faster.